# setup.exe -> Install VS 2010 does not do anything

Tags: visual-studio-2010

when I double click setup.exe, then click on the Install VS 2010 link, nothing happens. I've tried running as administrator, to no avail.

this means I have VS 2010 but I can't use it fml.  Please help!

thanks.

Comment: look in the event viewer and report back

Comment: Are you running the setup program from an ISO that you downloaded? The ISO may be corrupt. You may try verifying the checksums, or downloading it again.

Comment: Also, you could try Microsoft's Log Collection Tool and post back the results. That may help us diagnose the problem more easily: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e0da314f-6216-4a18-bc6b-7d29cf83af20&displaylang=en

Comment: process monitor shows me nothing, trying log collection thing now; and this is my 2nd iso I'm trying. #frustrating!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there have been a couple of similar issues discussed on the MSDN forums regarding difficulties installing VS 2010. Here's a few things I came up with to try:

- If you have handwriting support
  turned on, try disabling it. Show the
  language bar on the taskbar,
  right-click on it, and choose
  Settings," then remove handwriting
  support from the list.
- [One poster](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/5767cc2d-b9be-4314-8d75-d8d5737fe966) suggested running
  "setup.exe /q /full". This will do an unattended install of the full package.
- Do you have Windows Search turned on? Try turning it off, at least during the install (open Services by
  typing "services.msc" in the Run
  dialog, find Windows Search in the
  list of services, and click Stop.
- If you have been trying to run the setup program
  from an ISO, copy the setup files to
  a folder on your hard drive and run setup from there.

When you say "nothing happens," is there any disk activity reading from the installation source media? I have never seen this problem before and I've installed VS too many times to count.

Comment: Cody - you just made my week. setup.exe /q /full did the trick.  I wish had enough rep on stackoverflow to bump up this answer 10 times.

Comment: someone else - can you bump up Cody's answer?? please! this is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I could just imagine the frustration you were experiencing, so I'm glad this worked for you.

Comment: Well, for me the third option works. If I mount the iso file, it just crashes with error code `0xc0000006`. Write it down here just in case someone need it :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you run VS2010 Setp.exe, run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Now, when you run setup.exe, it Process Monitor will tell you exactly what it is doing. See if there is any activity. You should also monitor the status and see if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and found the following entry in the *Windows Application Event Log*:

> Access to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\setup.exe` has been restricted by your Administrator by location with policy rule `{1f05d944-2d64-4ad8-a99d-c1f4aac13cac}` placed on path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\\*.exe`

So I searched the registry for the guid referenced in the message and found it under `HKLM_SOFTWARE_Policies_Microsoft_Windows_safer_codeidentifiers_0_Path_{guid}`

At this location there is a `ValueName` of `ItemData` with the Value of 
`%LocalAppData%\Temp\\*.exe`

I changed this to be `%LocalAppData%\Temp1\\*.exe`. Since the `Temp1` folder doesn't exist the policy had no effect. The setup program was able to completely finish.